# Angular js. Inject service in router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can i inject a service into my router so that its result (json) will be available all over the application?

Router:

```
export default ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, MainController, ConfigService) {

$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    controller: 'MainController',
    resolve: {

      /* @ngInject */
      someResolve: (ConfigService) =>
        ConfigService.config()
    }
});

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}];
```

Service:

```
export default function ConfigService() {
return ['$http', function($http) {

    this.config = function() {
        return $http({
            url: '../json/config.json',
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
    };
}];
}
```

Maincontroller

```
export default function MainController () {
return ['$scope','$location','ConfigService','$window', function($scope, $location, ConfigService, $window) {

    ConfigService.config();

}];
}
```

Comment: Where do you want this JSON to be stored? e.g in $rootScope, a global, a local variable to a service with a getter etc?

Comment: I want it to be stored so that the whole app can access it from the very beginning. How thats done does not really matter for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MainController and ConfigService do not have any provider specified... Your statement should be like

```
export default ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','MainController', 'ConfigService', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, MainController, ConfigService) {}
```

Comment: still this problem remains the same for your router... just replace your first line of router with this code...

Comment: Thanks, but then i get: "$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: MainController"

Comment: that is unknown provider error..  that means you might have forgotten to add some script src to be added to your index.html page...

Comment: I will certainly keep helping you but i solved the error of injecting service into router.. So please can i get the vote up and mark as correct?

Comment: thats nice of you. What do you suggest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114857/discussion-between-tirthraj-barot-and-user2952238).

Answer (score 0):

Do it in the resolve.

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    controller: 'MainController',
    resolve: {

      /* @ngInject */
      someResolve: (ConfigService) =>
        ConfigService.config()
    }
});
```

Then your 'ConfigService' can be injected into the controller, and used (the result of the config()). Edited to use the correct service name and so on.

Comment: Thank you. i added your code do my router. but when i run in i did not get anything back from the service..?

Comment: its not even executing its request to ''config.json'

Comment: Thats what i did as well. Still not working as expected.

Comment: The call to ConfigService.config() - if you do it in the controller and console.log it out - does it return something as you would expect?

Comment: It does not make the call at all.

Comment: I have updated my code in the first post and added the maincontroller.